#  How might I hide article details in Joomla 1.7?

Tags: joomla

How might I hide article details in Joomla 1.7?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic (this is not a programming question). Please support the [Joomla proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34294/joomla-answers) on area51 if you'd like a dedicated Joomla equivalent of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

Menu Manager > Category > Article > Article Options >

From there you can hide things like the author, date, and such.